# Loading Xml to jgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

i am using jgrid. i am creating a specific XML as per the jgrid format using c#(Castle Monorail).
i am sending data to view in string format and pass it to "url:" but its not working.

but if i m passing the xml file path to the "url:" its working and data is showing in the grid.

Is i m doing mistake any where.
Should i have to paas data to view in any other format.

Please, Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use

```
datatype: 'xmlstring'
```

instead of `'xml'`

and put your string in

```
datastr : mystr
```

Comment: It Still not working. from controller i m sending the data in propertybag and geting data in viwe i can see the xml in alert but it not get load in jgrid.

Comment: try to datatype: 'xmlstring',and put your string in datastr : mystr,
look on example in http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data&s[]=xmlstring